# When checking out a file, other projects in the solution get checked out

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Quite often, if I make a change to a Integration Services Package in Project A, for some reason, Team Foundation Services (TFS) will checkout the `.dtproj` and the `.dtproj.vspscc` of other projects that are part of my solution (but not all projects).

It seems like that some packages/projects have a link to the other projects and are checking those files out whne I make a change to a file from another project. Has anyone had this happen before and know what it could be?

Comment: What changes did you make to Project A? What's the relationship between Project A and other Projects? I've tested on my side by creating a solution with two Integration Services Projects, and check in the solution to VSTS. After add a task in Package.dtsx in one of the Project, I can only see the Package.dtsx in one Project is checked out. I couldn't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Is there any changes applied to these files?

Comment: No, it says the files are the same. I noticed today, for example, that when running a package, it then checked out 3 other projects files in my solution (not all of them though). This has also just recently started happening to a co-worker. I have our master branch locked, for example, and I ran a package. First time, it ran fine. Second time, during running, I got a few "Access Denied" errors as it was trying to check out the other project files. I can't see any reference to other project files inside of any of these files.

Comment: Can you try the workaround here: http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/jonathon%20eveoconnor/post/Stop-Automatic-checkout-of-SSIS-Packages-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Unfortunately that isn't our issue. We have had that issue in the past mind you, but our .database files are in source control and all .dtprof files are referencing the correct file